# Error setting default accordion item in class condition

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-4

In my laravel 5.7 / Vuejs ( vue": "^2.6.10" ) / "bootstrap": "^4.3.1" application 
using accordion I want in debugging purpose show 1 block openec with template like:

```
            <div :id="'collapse'+nextStateWithRegion.id" v-bind:class="'collapse'+{ ' show' : nextStateWithRegion.id == debugging_state_id }" :aria-labelledby="'heading'+nextStateWithRegion.id"
                 data-parent="#accordion_hostels_by_location">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!--{{ nextStateWithRegion.regionsOfStateArray }}-->
                    <ul>

                        <li v-for="nextRegionOfState, index in nextStateWithRegion.regionsOfStateArray" :key="nextRegionOfState.id">
                            <!--nextRegionOfState::{{ nextRegionOfState }}-->
                            <router-link :to="{ name: 'hostelsByRegion', params: { region_id: nextRegionOfState.id, state_id : nextRegionOfState.state_id } }"
                                         class="nav-link">{{ nextRegionOfState.name }}
                                <small>( {{ nextRegionOfState.related_common_hostels_count }} hostels with {{ nextRegionOfState.related_featured_hostels_count }}
                                    featured)</small>
                            </router-link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

but result is different, as I see not ‘ show’ string added to the class, but ‘[object Object]’ :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Ewi.jpg

Which way is correct ?

Thanks!

Comment: use array syntax instead of string concatenation to bind dynamic classes: `v-bind:class="['collapse', { 'show': nextStateWithRegion.id == debugging_state_id }]"`

Comment: Thanks! It helped